# Remove script under profile.d which "freezes" the system on boot

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there a way during the boot to go to console instead of loading all "things"? Need to go to profile.d-directory and remove script which "freezes" system during the boot.

I don't know the word for Linux, but like in windows "boot to safe mode"

I'm using Rasbian Jessie.

Comment: Would not be easier to mount the SD card somewhere else and edit the file system?

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro Thanks. I have a laptop with SD-card reader...What method do you  propose to get this done by editing the file system on laptop? Should I edit my Question that you can write answer for that method?

Comment: If it has linux you just mount the card, otherwise boot with a live Linux distro, for instance knoppix.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a [single user mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_user_mode). The way to invoke it depends on your exact distro. Very often it consists of just adding some boot-time option ("1" or "single").

This can be done from your bootloader.

In Grub just highlight the kernel you want to use, press 'e', go down to line starting with 'linux' and add the boot-time option to the end of that line. Then press enter to boot that kernel with that option.

For Debian the way the process is described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/482079/debian-boot-to-single-user-mode). Hopefully it should be the same for Raspbian Jessie which is debian-based.